# 'Cannot find module' when importing shared code between frontend and backend using path aliases typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm developing a full stack TS app and came across some code that needed to be shared between both the frontend and the backend. For that I moved that code to a shared folder. I've figured the imports would be too big if using only relative paths but aliasing the path doesn't seem to work as well.

Each side (both frontend and backend) live as individual projects with their individual `tsconfig.json` file.

The directory structure is as follows:

```
|--- root
   | --- client
      | --- (client-side code)
   | --- server
      | --- (server-side code)
   | --- shared
      | --- (shared code)
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext" 
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "build",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["../shared/*"],
      "src/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "files": ["src/types.d.ts"]
}
//
```

and an example import like this:

```typescript
import { Tree } from '@/crdt/tree';
import {DeleteMessage, InsertMessage, Node} from '@/crdt/types';
```

- Backend - Express
- Frontend - React + Vite

This is an example of the given error:

```
cannot find module '@/crdt/tree'
```

As I've mentioned, I tried configuring the `tsconfig.json` file and the IDE (in this case VS Code) can find the folders inside shared when using the custom alias, however it crashes on runtime. This error was given by `nodemon`.

Comment: And what do you have actually _resolving_ those paths?

Comment: I've configured the 'paths' option in tsconfig as shown above but it still doesn't work. From what I've read it is enough for same-project imports, so shouldn't it work for external imports?

Comment: `paths` tells the compiler that it will work at runtime, but doesn't actually make it so. You also need something to _actually resolve the module_.

Comment: So what do I need to add for it to work?  I've also added the 'tsconfig-paths' as Baltazar Ottonello said, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

just in case, you need to install tsconfig-paths

```
npm install --save-dev tsconfig-paths
```

and in the main file do this

```
import 'tsconfig-paths/register';
```